# How to handle routing problems in heroku with angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, routes

I am trying to deploy a project in angular to heroku, locally it works but in heroku i am getting this error regarding routing:

```
    ERROR in : Unexpected value '[object Object]' exported by the module 'FeatureRoutingModule in /tmp/build_f3526f025f2ad2799e342a115f1ccdaf/src/app/app.routes.ts'

     chunk {scripts} scripts.1ddbc8b5858d4c91e16d.js (scripts) 281 kB [entry] [rendered]

npm ERR! platon@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `ng build --prod`
```

and the my routing code is:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },


];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(APP_ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule, APP_ROUTES]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule {}

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Comment: Are you saying you can run `ng build --prod` on your project locally and you don't get that error? Deploying and building are two different things.

Comment: actually i have "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod" in my package.json file and locally is working fine, but what is weird is that i have the connection with github and in the console log from heroku says "push rejected" ..

Comment: Remove `APP_ROUTES` from the exports array.